# Python, trying to install a package gives WinError2

Tags: python

I'm trying to install a package to my python in pyCharm. And im getting this error, WinError2 'unknown path'. Anyone got an idea what can cause this?

Is there a way to manually install the package? And would that even help,

the package is called pyAutioGUI

```
Collecting PyAutoGUI
      Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.31.zip
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymsgbox in c:\users\rasmus\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages (from PyAutoGUI)
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyTweening>=1.0.1 in c:\users\rasmus\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages (from PyAutoGUI)
    Collecting Pillow (from PyAutoGUI)
      Using cached Pillow-2.9.0.tar.gz
    Collecting pyscreeze (from PyAutoGUI)
      Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.7.zip
    Installing collected packages: Pillow, pyscreeze, PyAutoGUI
      Running setup.py install for Pillow
        Complete output from command C:\Python\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\\Pillow\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-yk7kfpka-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
        Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile: 4 processes
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageFileIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\OleFileIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        copying PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        running egg_info
        writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
        writing Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
        writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
        warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

        reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
        writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        copying PIL\OleFileIO-README.md -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\PIL
        warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

        running build_ext
        building 'PIL._imaging' extension
        error: [WinError 2] Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet

        ----------------------------------------

    Command "C:\Python\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\\Pillow\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-yk7kfpka-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\Pillow
```

Comment: Which Python version did you try? Is it Py3.5?

Comment: It appears some people need to install the [Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) to get Pillow to work under Python 3.5 on Windows. You might want to try that.

Answer (score 0):

The package is available via pip.

You could try manually in terminal by:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

If you're not familiar with the python package manager pip, [here's the link to pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).

Comment: I tried writing that in the terminal, and getting same error.

Comment: Have you tried with admin privileges!? It seems to happen when trying to install pillow as dependency. Can you try to install pillow first and see if this works!?

Comment: Getting same error when trying to install pillow, with and without admin privilieges. I recently deleted python and installed it again, but placed it in another directory than last time. Could this be cause for trouble?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I found something on the Pillow website: Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL. Check if PIL is installed.

Comment: PIL is not installed.